# Apple App Transfer And push FireBase cloud messaging

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

I'd like to transfer my application Apple Ios from my account to another Apple dev account in the near future, my application uses FireBase cloud messaging to receive notifications

What exactly should I do once the transfer is done ?

Should I just update the APNs authentication key on the FireBase console in Project parameters ? Should I also change the team ID on the fireBase console ?

Does this mean generating a new GoogleService-Info.plist file and therefore an application update ? or no need ?

thank you

I want to ensure the continuity of notifications without changing the Firebase account.

Answer (score 0):

From what I know, when you successfully transferred an app to another Dev account.

- Apple Dev Account is changed, so the Push (*.cert/p12) or Service Key (*.p8) will have to be generated by using the new Apple Dev Account.
- Then upload this p8 or p12 to the existing iOS app on the current/same Firebase project. To let FCM know that it should send the Push Notification to the new target (App A in Team B, before it is App A in Team A)
- The link between the Firebase iOS app and the Native iOS app is a Bundle Identifier only.
- Apple Dev Account is changed so CloudKit, StoreKit,.. will have to be configured again on the new Apple Dev Account.

Comment: Thank you for you answer, so there is no need to make an update of the App ? juste create a new p8 and upload it in the fireBase console , how about the teamID ? Doesn't it make any difference to keep the old one or update it with the new one ?

Comment: @ChakibTemal Yes. But it is for display only, so if you forget to change it, the new app still works fine.